MenuDrawer can't fetch the correct provider route
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MenuDrawer Widget
This happens because you used a BuildContext that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

You added a new provider in your main.dart and performed a hot-reload.
To fix, perform a hot-restart.

The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
other routes will not be able to access that provider.

You used a BuildContext that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
Make sure that MenuDrawer is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
For example, instead of:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
    // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
    child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
  );
}

consider using builder like so:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
    builder: (context, child) {
      // No longer throws
      return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
    }
  );
}



I was expecting of opening a drawer with some buttons but it's giving this error, i tried gpt. it was working good but some error occurred in the same file, when i changed it, this error came in
